# How to interact with drop down list in webscraping?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, dropdown

I'm trying to navigate in this site: https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/mensual/ with ChromeDriver.

There are two drop down lists but I'm specially interested just in one:

[image]

And I want to select the option "Solo Proyectos"

For that reason I have this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# Inicialización del driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Entrando al sitio indicado en la pregunta
driver.get("https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/mensual/")
time.sleep(5)

# Filtro

Lista=Select(driver.find_element("id","ctl00_CPH1_DrpActProy"))
Lista.select_by_value("Proyecto")
```

Also I tried with this:

```
# Inicialización del driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Entrando al sitio indicado en la pregunta
driver.get("https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/mensual/")
time.sleep(5)

# Filtro

Lista=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_DrpActProy"]/option[3]')
Lista.click()
```

But they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that this website uses frames:

```
<frameset rows="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
   <frame name="frame0" id="frame0" src="Navegar.aspx" scrolling="yes" />
   <noframes>
      <body><p>Esta página usa marcos pero su explorador no lo permite.</p>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3&ns=1&cb=871613096" async></script></body>
   </noframes>
</frameset>
```

So you should switch to the right one before try to select:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.NAME,'frame0'))
```

or

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID,'frame0'))
```

###### Example

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# Inicialización del driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Entrando al sitio indicado en la pregunta
driver.get("https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/mensual/")

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.NAME,'frame0'))

Lista=Select(driver.find_element("id","ctl00_CPH1_DrpActProy"))
Lista.select_by_value("Proyecto")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question please. Why 'frame0'? Is it in the page html?